# Concentration term PPM

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, concentration

What volume do we assume when the concentration is written as mass by volume ppm?

I mean when mass by volume percentage is say 20%, we can say that 20g solute is present in ***100 ml*** solution.
So if it is written that concentration of given solution is say 20ppm (mass by volume) how can I understand this concentration term like I did in above example?